# How do you obscure publicly published code?

Tags: security

Or tell me if I'm misunderstanding what I'm seeing, but check out this link.

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js

See how all the variables are like a,b,c and all the code is compacted into no space at all? Makes it completely unreadable, incomprehensible. I see it a lot. The google search page is the same way if you view the code.

I'm guessing this is an obsfuscation tactic, and I'm wondering how it's done. Obviously they don't really have code that looks like that when they're writing it-- it must be put through some sort of transform. How is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not primarily an obfuscation tactic. JQuery's full readable source is publicly available.

That is minified code. The main purpose is to make it load faster, and transfer over the network faster.

There are multiple minify tools out there. I use the Google Closure Compiler which does much more than minify, it also does some optimization and does a nice job of finding coding errors, but also produces very compact code.

Minified or compiled js is hard to read and so might serve you as an obfuscation approach. Most people probably aren't using it for that reason.

Comment: WOW Thank you, that is *immensely* useful. I never knew that was an option/could be done.

Comment: Although, surely this is an obfuscation tactic *sometimes*? On google's page, for instance? It does work well in that sense, I feel.

Comment: @Aerovistae Sure, it obfuscates, and some people value that more than the performance aspect. I'll change my adverb to primarily. I guess most of the minify methods are not super strong obfuscation compared to the obfuscators out there for Java or .Net code. Google Closure's Advanced setting makes it more challenging, if you can use that.

Answer (score 2):

The real value of this approach ( minification ) is to reduce the size of the code, consequently decreasing the download time and so making user pages available much more quickly.

There are quite a few tools designed for this purpose as a search of Google will reveal.

The security outcomes are minimal because there are also tools designed to prettify JavaScript code which will turn minified code back into something readable. As everyone knows, security through obscurity is very nearly equivalent to no security at all. If you are putting code where it is publically available, people can read it. The trick is to ensure that this doesn't matter.